# Почему начальное значение хуков не может быть задано пустым объектом?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть этот setProd Hooks

```
export interface faceProduct {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly prodState: string;
  readonly shipping: string;
  readonly sold: string;
  readonly alt: string;
  readonly material: string;
  readonly location: string;
  readonly src: string[];
  readonly color: string[];
  readonly saiz: string[];
  readonly price: string;
}

export interface faceProductList extends faceProduct {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly to: string;
}

 const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>({});
```

Я хочу, чтобы начальные значения были пустым объектом. Но я получаю ошибку ..
Но если написать.

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>(Object);
```

все работает с чем это связано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что ты в интерфейсе явно указал, каким должен быть объект, можно сделать так:

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList | {}>({});
```